# Error when calling JAX-WS service method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have an issue with calling my JAX-WS Service method. My service seems to deploy successfully.

The interface looks like:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://bioflip.org/wsdl")
public interface IUserService { //@WebMethod stubs go here }
```

and the implementation looks like:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
        portName = "UserPort",
        serviceName = "UserService",
        targetNamespace = "http://bioflip.org/wsdl",
        endpointInterface = "IUserService")
public class UserService implements IUserService
{
 //@Override implementations of the interface web methods go here.
}
```

Here is the header of the WSDL that results when I run the service:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://bioflip.org/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="UserService" targetNamespace="http://bioflip.org/wsdl">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://bioflip.org/wsdl" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://bioflip.org/wsdl" version="1.0">
```

The WSDL can be found at the address:

```
http://localhost:8080/BioFlipService/webservices/UserService?wsdl
```

If I just visit:

```
http://localhost:8080/BioFlipService/webservices/UserService
```

I get the message:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

I assume that is fine. However, when attempting to access the service from my client, like so:

```
IUserService userServiceClient;
Service userService = Service.create(
        new URL("http://localhost:8080/BioFlipService/webservices/UserService?wsdl"),
        new QName("http://bioflip.org/wsdl","UserService"));
userServiceClient = userService.getPort(IUserService.class);

boolean enrolled1 = userServiceClient.enrollUser(zach);
```

I get the following error client side:

```
Sep 08, 2014 10:58:52 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://bioflip.org/wsdl}UserService from WSDL: http://localhost:8080/BioFlipService/webservices/UserService?wsdl
Sep 08, 2014 10:58:52 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://bioflip.org/wsdl}UserService from WSDL: http://localhost:8080/BioFlipService/webservices/UserService?wsdl
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: null 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.enrollUser(Unknown Source)
    at BioFlip.Bioflip.main(Bioflip.java:34)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Unmarshalling Error: null 
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:845)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1705)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1538)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1445)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:660)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 2 more
```

And the following error server side:

```
INFO: Server startup in 1524 ms
Sep 08, 2014 10:58:52 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://bioflip.org/wsdl}UserService#{http://bioflip.org/wsdl}enrollUser has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: null 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:872)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:693)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsServlet.service(WsServlet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:833)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:861)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:859)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:691)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$Factory.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:620)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:501)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$Factory.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:318)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: BioFlip.User.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at BioFlip.UserFactory.createUser(UserFactory.java)
    ... 48 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. uhh.. I don't know anything about jax-ws but that last thing at the bottom, "NoSuchMethodError", means that the JVM can't find the constructor BioFlip.User..
Has that class been deployed to the server successfully? Is it the same version you used to compile BioFlip.UserFactory?

Basically, if you compile two java files then you change/compile one so it is incompatible with the other this can happen.